# Referencing inner classes in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I reference an inner class in Dart?

Specifically I am trying to retrieve the assetName property of an Image passed to a button handler function in Flutter.

Right now I am dereferencing the classes one part at a time, as follows:

```
// sample Images

const square = Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/square.png'));
const triangle = Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/triangle.png'));
const circle = Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/circle.png'));


// callback handler for GestureDetector onTap.
// buttonVal is either the text OR an image displayed
// in a custom button.
// if buttonVal is an image, it will be one of the above.

String compute(dynamic buttonVal, String result) {
  if (buttonVal.runtimeType != String) {
    
    // ------ here is current dereferencing code --------
    Image im = buttonVal as Image;
    AssetImage ai = im.image;
    String an = ai.assetName;

    print('------------ $an ----------');
. . .
}
```

Does Dart have a simpler syntax for doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: `String an = (buttonVal as Image).image.assetName;` ?

Comment: Thanks but that gives me: 
error: The getter 'assetName' isn't defined for the type 'ImageProvider<dynamic>'. \

Comment: Does nesting work: `((buttonVal as Image) as AssetImage).assetName;`?

Comment: That produces an error:
error: The getter 'image' isn't defined for the type 'AssetImage'.

Comment: Getting closer,
String an = (buttonVal as AssetImage).assetName; compiles but gives a runtime error.

The following _CastError was thrown while handling a gesture:
type 'Image' is not a subtype of type 'AssetImage' in type cast

Comment: oh ok. Then as @Chazman commented going ahead with nesting is the way `String an = ((buttonVal as Image).image as AssetImage).assetName; `

Comment: Thank you both!  The following works:

 String an = ((buttonVal as Image).image as AssetImage).assetName;

Comment: dev-aentgs:  that last one worked. Thanks again.

"C" was my primary language and you guys taught me a lot about casting in Dart.